# session fixation - delete session after login and make a new session - but user is then not logged in anymore

Tags: security, session, authentication, jsf-2, java-ee-6

I use jsf2.0 and java ee6 on a JBoss AS 7

i have a LoginController.java looking like this:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "loginController")
@SessionScoped
public class LoginController implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1119172305268193508L;

    @Inject
    private UserProvider userProvider;

    @PostConstruct
    public void initNewUser() {
        user = new User();
    }

    private User user;

    private String accountName;

    private String password;

    public String ownLogin() throws Exception {

        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
                .getExternalContext().getRequest();


        if (accountName != null) {
            try {


                if (exists(accountName)) {

                    user = userProvider.findUserByAccountName(accountName);

                    if (verifyPassword(user, password)) {

                        userProvider.saveChangedUser(user);


                        // OWASP SAYS: after login, destroy the session make a new one 
                        // a so called handover
                        // Destroy the session
                        FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();

                        HttpSession session = (HttpSession) facesContext.getExternalContext().getSession(false);
                        if(session != null){
                            session.invalidate();
                        }
                        // create new session after logout
                        session = (HttpSession) facesContext.getExternalContext().getSession(true);
                    setLogin(true);
            }                   
    }

/* some getters and setters */

}
```

The OWASP says, for security reason that after a login the sessions should be deleted (see: [V3.7](http://code.google.com/p/owasp-asvs/wiki/Verification_V3))

i do this in my code at this point:

```
FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();

                            HttpSession session = (HttpSession) facesContext.getExternalContext().getSession(false);
                            if(session != null){
                                session.invalidate();
                            }
                            // create new session after logout
                            session = (HttpSession) facesContext.getExternalContext().getSession(true);
```

First, I delete the old session, then I make a new session.
After this, I set the login true...

Of course, after running through the whole code, the user is not logged in, because the LoginController was managed in the old session scope - and in the new session scope there is a new LoginController in the scope without the loged in user...

Is there any way, to add a new LoginController to the new session after creation?

Or what is the common way to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you invalidate the session, all of its attributes will be trashed by end of response. You're however setting the login status on a session scoped bean instance which lives in the old session only.

You basically need to manually recreate the session scoped bean and put it in the new session *after* the invalidate.

```
ExternalContext externalContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
externalContext.invalidateSession();
LoginController loginController = new LoginController();
loginController.setUser(user);
externalContext.getSessionMap().put("loginController", loginController);
```

*(look ma, no ugly `javax.servlet` imports anymore!)*

By the way, when you go this way, you could also just make your `LoginController` a view scoped bean and deal with `User` in the session only.

```
ExternalContext externalContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
externalContext.invalidateSession();
externalContext.getSessionMap().put("user", user);
```

*(it'll be available by `#{user}` throughout the EL context, also in managed properties; it does not necessarily need to be a JSF managed bean)*

Comment: and again...  thanks you! this works perfect.... if i need the userProvider for the logout again... but if i try to logout, i make something like: `loggedIn = false;
  user.setLoggedIn(false);userProvider.saveChangedUser(user); ExternalContext externalContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext(); externalContext.invalidateSession();` but then the userprovider is empty. i alsow tryed to put the userProvider to the session too, but not working - and after that error, i can not login again - because the userProvider is null...

Comment: ... ok, i see the userProvider is not empty - but the entityManager inside the userProvider (and everything else which is `@Injected` or `@Produces` is empty)

Comment: `@Inject` is of CDI and doesn't work in JSF `@ManagedBean`, only in CDI `@Named`. Make the `UserProvider` a `@Stateless` and inject it by `@EJB`.

Comment: Why does his LoginController has to be viewscoped? Requestscoped would be good too no ? Just to be clear

Comment: @Ced: Depends. Starters often grab `@SessionScoped` when `@RequestScoped` didn't seem to work out. But if a `@RequestScoped` works fine too, by all means use it.